# Number assigned to a variable using Case Switch returning 0 instead of correct result

Tags: javascript, html

I am a beginner in JavaScript and I would like to simulate an exercise using HTML and JavaScript. Basically, I have two inputs that take 1: the name of a product and 2) the quantity of this item. When user click on a button, the function that calculates the total amount for that item is executed. On this function, I use switch statement in order to calculate the right $amount according to the product. Then the function should print the itemTotal which is the result of the itemQ (Quantity of the item) * a fix value for that item (3.5 for eggs). But itemTotal appear with 0 zero. It seems that the switch statement does not recognize it. If I make it a local value inside switch, then I cannot used outside of switch statement. What can I do? Any ideas?

```js
function calTotItemA() {
  var item = document.getElementById("itemName").value;
  var itemQ = document.getElementById("itemQuantity").value;
  var itemTotal = 0;
  switch (item) {
    case "eggs":
      this.itemTotal = 3.5 * itemQ;
      break;
    case "milk":
      this.itemTotal = 4.5 * itemQ;
      break;
  }
  document.getElementById("itemTotalDisplay").innerHTML = itemTotal;
}
```

```css
header {
  background-color: #83BD26;
}
h1 {
  text-align: center;
}
#pad {
  background-color: #B5BFA4;
}
#container {
  border: 3px solid black;
}
#itemBox {
  height: 3px;
  widht:
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <header>
    <h1>My Cash Register</h1>
  </header>
  <div id="pad">
    <form>Enter item
      <input type="text" id="itemName" value=" ">
    </form>
    <form>Enter quantity of the item
      <input type="number" id="itemQuantity" value="0">
    </form>
    <button onclick="calTotItemA()">Calculate Total Amount per Item</button>
    <p>The total amount for this item:</p>
    <p id="itemTotalDisplay"></p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: just FYI , a dropdown option has a value and text , so it would look like <option value="3.5">eggs</option>   then you get the value and it returns the price , you don't need to type out a switch/case in your code

Comment: also - they all go in the same form

Comment: Thank you for your advice Scott, I really appreciate it. I tried option value but it only returns string. I need a number, lets say the cost of the item as a number so that I can multiply it for the itemQ (quantity of the item which is already a number, no a string)

Comment: you can multiply a string number *1 to turn it into a number

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```js
function calTotItemA() {
  var item = document.getElementById("itemName").value;
  var itemQ = document.getElementById("itemQuantity").value;
  var itemTotal = 0;
  switch (item) {
    case "eggs":
      itemTotal = 3.5 * itemQ;
      break;
    case "milk":
      itemTotal = 4.5 * itemQ;
      break;
  }
  document.getElementById("itemTotalDisplay").innerHTML = itemTotal;
}
```

```css
header {
  background-color: #83BD26;
}
h1 {
  text-align: center;
}
#pad {
  background-color: #B5BFA4;
}
#container {
  border: 3px solid black;
}
#itemBox {
  height: 3px;
  widht:
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <header>
    <h1>My Cash Register</h1>
  </header>
  <div id="pad">
    <form>Enter item
      <input type="text" id="itemName" value="">
    </form>
    <form>Enter quantity of the item
      <input type="number" id="itemQuantity" value="0">
    </form>
    <button onclick="calTotItemA()">Calculate Total Amount per Item</button>
    <p>The total amount for this item:</p>
    <p id="itemTotalDisplay"></p>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Don't use `this`.** Check out the snippet above, all I did was remove `this` (and also remove the space in the `value` attribute for `itemName` because it was making me add an extra space by mistake)

Your code should be:

```
function calTotItemA() {
  var item = document.getElementById("itemName").value;
  var itemQ = document.getElementById("itemQuantity").value;
  var itemTotal = 0;
  switch (item) {
    case "eggs":
      itemTotal = 3.5 * itemQ;
      break;
    case "milk":
      itemTotal = 4.5 * itemQ;
      break;
  }
  document.getElementById("itemTotalDisplay").innerHTML = itemTotal;
}
```

The keyword `this` behaves differently than on other languages, please have a look at [the docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this)

When used inside a function, it either returns the global object (window) when not in strict mode, or undefined or the base caller when in strict mode.

> ## Function context
>
> Inside a function, the value of this depends on how the function is called.
>
> ### Simple call
>
> ```
> function f1(){   return this; }
>
> f1() === window; // global object
> ```
>
> In this case, the value of this is
>   not set by the call. Since the code is not in strict mode, the value
>   of this must always be an object so it defaults to the global object.
>
> ```
> function f2(){
>   "use strict"; // see strict mode
>   return this; }
>
> f2() === undefined;
> ```
>
> In strict mode, the value of this remains at
>   whatever it's set to when entering the execution context. If it's not
>   defined, it remains undefined. It can also be set to any value, such
>   as null or 42 or "I am not this".
>
> > Note: In the second example, this should be undefined, because f2 was
> >     called without providing any base (e.g. window.f2()). This feature
> >     wasn't implemented in some browsers when they first started to support
> >     strict mode. As a result, they incorrectly returned the window object.

Comment: Thank you all I got it. I removed "this" and the extraspace for itemName.

Answer (score 0):

The only problem I saw was that you had a space in the value of the itemName. Unknowningly, I find myself typing "eggs" and getting " eggs". If I backspaced it would work fine. As the comments, I'd recommend using a dropdown to better control the input values.

Fiddle: [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/ax7su6nh/)

```
<div id="container">
    <header>
        <h1>My Cash Register</h1>
    </header>
    <div id="pad">
        <div>Enter item
            <select id="itemName">
                <option value="eggs">Eggs</option>
                <option value="milk">Milk</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div>Enter quantity of the item
            <input type="number" id="itemQuantity" value="0">
        </div>
        <button id="button">Calculate Total Amount per Item</button>
        <p>The total amount for this item:</p>
        <p id="itemTotalDisplay"></p>
    </div>
</div>`
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is working well.

All you have to do is one of this two things:

Add a trim() to the line where you get the item (it will remove all the spaces before and after the string you get in the input, is a good practice to do it always):

```
var item = document.getElementById("itemName").value.trim();
```

Or remove the space of the item input value:

```
<input type="text" id="itemName" value="">
```

The problem is that you are getting the Item value with a space at the beginning " eggs", so the switch ignores your input because there is no case that matches that.

Also, as a recommendation, do not use a form for every input. The form tag should surround all the inputs an labels that are needed in the operation you are making.

Comment: Thank you Felipe for the form recommendation. I used them since I thought they help to label the input. I will verify that. On the other hand, I would like to know if you noticed the space just by looking at it or using web develpment tools..

Comment: I went to jsfiddle.net and ran your code to see how it behaved, there I noticed the space.